# Print results with unique names

Tags: php, sql

I have the below function:

```
function getStoresDisplay($data, $page_number, $nb_display) {
$nb_stores = $data['nb_stores'];
$list = $data['list'];
$current_address = $data['address'];

if($current_address=='') $current_address_display = '&nbsp;';
else $current_address_display=$current_address;

$display .= '<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="d">';
$display .= '<li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="a">'.$current_address_display.'<span class="ui-li-count">'.$nb_stores.'</span></li>';
for($i=0; $i<count($list); $i++) {
    $id = $list[$i]['id'];
    $name = $list[$i]['name'];
    $logo = $list[$i]['logo'];
    $address = $list[$i]['address'];
    $distance = $list[$i]['distance'];
    $created = $list[$i]['created'];

    $display .= '<li><a href="javascript:" class="displayStoreDetails" id="'.$id.'">';
    if($logo!='') $display .= '<img src="'.$logo.'" style="margin-top:18px;">';
    $display .= '<h3>'.$name;
    $display .= '</h3>';
    //if($current_address!='') $display .= '<span class="ui-li-count"><font color="red"><small>'.ceil($distance).' '.$GLOBALS['distance_unit'].'</small></font></span>';
    $display .= '<p>'.$address.'</p>';
    if($current_address!='') $display .= '<p><small>Dista da te: </small><font color="red"><small>'.ceil($distance).' '.$GLOBALS['distance_unit'].'</small></font></p>';
    $display .= '</a></li>';
}
$display .= '</ul><br>';

$display .= '<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-theme="a" style="text-align:right;" >';
    if($page_number>1) $display .= '<a href="javascript:" id="displayStoresListNextPreviousBtn" page_number="'.($page_number-1).'" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l" data-theme="d">Previous</a>';
    $display .= '<a href="javascript:" data-role="button" data-theme="d"><span id="pageNumberReload">'.$page_number.'</span></a>';
    if($nb_stores>($page_number*$nb_display)) $display .= '<a href="javascript:" id="displayStoresListNextPreviousBtn" page_number="'.($page_number+1).'" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-theme="d">Next</a>';
$display .= '</div>';

return $display;
```

I want that it will print only results with unique names ( `$name = $list[$i]['name'];` ).
I have same item in different categories, so I want that it should not print duplicate items with same name.

How can I do this?

Comment: Post a sample of what's in `$data`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$unique_names = array();
for($i=0; $i<count($list); $i++) {
  if (in_array($list[$i]['name'], $unique_names)) { continue; }
  $unique_names[] = $list[$i]['name'];
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your following code:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($list); $i++) {
    $id = $list[$i]['id'];
    $name = $list[$i]['name'];
```

for this one:

```
$names = array();
for($i=0; $i<count($list); $i++) {
    $id = $list[$i]['id'];
    $name = $list[$i]['name'];
    if (in_array($name,$names)) {
       continue;
    }
    $names[] = $name;
```

that will skip duplicated entries from the loop and do what you wanted.